# JOptionPane action listener posting on exit

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I created a button called addSupplier applied to a frame, then I created an action listener so once the addSupplier button is pressed it would create a JOptionPane which has a panel attached with JTextFields.

```
        addSupplier.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,addSupplierPanel,"Add new supplier", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            suppNameInsert = suppNameIn.getText();
            System.out.println(suppNameInsert);
        }
    });
```

The purpose of this JOptionPane is to add information to the JTextFields to then be processed and sent into a MySQL database, however, because the JOptionPane is opening in the action listener if I press Okay OR the 'X' out button it will print whatever is in the JTextField.

I only want this to happen when I press 'OKAY' but I assume that I will have to go about generating the JOptionPane in a separate way?

Comment: I think a [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) is probably a better fit for your needs. Alternatively, consider using a different `JOptionPane` method. Maybe `showConfirmDialog()` or `showInputDialog()` or `showOptionDialog()`.

Comment: I'm actually using JOptionPane because it stops users from being able to interact with any other frames when it's open. This is all linked to a database so it seemed a simpler way of stopping data being manipulated in multiple ways at once, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Using a JOptionPane is fine. You just need to use the appropriate "showXXX(…)" method as has already been suggested. You should NOT use showMessageDialog() since it is not designed to return a parameter indicating which button was clicked to close the dialog. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples of using the other show methods.

Comment: The issue is that when I click the 'X' option in the top right of the window it will still run through and System.out.println function even though I've clicked the X in the top right.

Changing the showXXX(...) changes the input and content of the pane but doesn't stop the exit out button from being seen as a button press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Changing the showXXX(...) changes the input and content of the pane but doesn't stop the exit out button from being seen as a button press?

You need to check the int parameter that was returned from the `showXXX(….)` method. This value will tell you which button was clicked.

Something like:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(…);

if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    // do your processing here
}
```

Comment: I didn't think to find if the status of the OK button is pressed, thanks for the simplified answer!